# Is a level 5 spell really more powerful than a level 8 spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I was looking at the various polymorph subschool spells, and I noticed that *[Baleful Polymorph](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/baleful-polymorph/)* has this interesting bit:

> Any polymorph effects on the target are **automatically** dispelled when a target fails to resist the effects of baleful polymorph, and as long as baleful polymorph remains in effect, the target cannot use other polymorph spells or effects to assume a new form.

(Emphasis mine.)

So would this mean that *[Polymorph Any Object](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph-any-object/)* would automatically be dispelled if the affected target failed the save on *Baleful Polymorph* (either on purpose or not)?

Personally, I think this would make it a bit overpowered, because even *[True Form](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-form/)* a level 4 spell A) has a limited duration and B) has to overcome a DC = 11 + caster level of the effect.

Comment: [Different direction, similar question.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70933/8610)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not overpowered.

Let me start by noting: the worst thing about failing your save against *baleful polymorph* is not that it removes your buff spell.  The worst thing about failing your save against *baleful polymorph* is that it turns you into a turtle.

There are lots of spells with similar effects, by the way -- for fifth level wizard spells I see *dismissal* and *dominate person* and *hostile juxtaposition* and *straitjacket* and *magic jar* which all follow this general pattern of "save or lose".

-- And, haha, most of these spells can also be used to get rid of *polymorph any object*.  For example, if you were a humanoid who was polymorphed into a dragon, and you fail your save against *magic jar*, the caster (now inhabiting your body) can force you to commit suicide, which breaks your *polymorph any object* effect.

---

It's worth noting: polymorph effects don't change the target's type, and *polymorph any object* isn't an exception to that as far as I know.  So, if you polymorphed a pebble into a dragon, I believe the dragon would not count as a "creature" and thus would not be a valid target for *baleful polymorph*.  I suspect this is not relevant to your use of *polymorph any object*, but I've included it for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

### No, it is not.

It's worth noting that "*powerful*" is relative here. A 8th level spell has a higher save DC and is harder to dispel or counter, and even to identify.

Also, [Polymorph Any Object](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph-any-object/) can also reproduce the effects of [Baleful Polymorph](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/baleful-polymorph/), so as a spell and considering it's usefulness, it is clearly more powerful. So everything you can do with the 5th level spell, you could also do with the 8th level spell, so **the 8th level spell is more powerful**.

Not to mention that [Dispel Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic/) is a 3rd level spell that can potentially remove the effects of even 9th level spells. We have to consider the objective of the spell instead of simply measuring which is more powerful regarding certain circunstances.

Now, for certain circunstances and uses of a spell, then maybe a lower level spell can be seen as more powerful (for being more useful) than a higher level spell, because it can do things that the higher level spell cannot.